# pass session variabel into another file using express-session

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I have 2 file, **app.js** and **login.js**, i need to pass my session from **app.js** into **login.js**, so i make class in **login.js** and define my session as `this.req.session.username`, when running the app, the error comes from **login.js** where it says `cannot read porperties of undefined (reading req)` which occure in **login.js** : `this.req.session.username`

anyway, here's my **app.js** :

```
//-----REQUIRE
const express           = require('express'),
      pug               = require('pug'),
      multer            = require('multer'),
      bodyParser        = require('body-parser'),
      session           = require('express-session'),
      flash             = require('connect-flash'),
      path              = require('path')
//-----
//-----
//-----
//-----
//-----
//-----CONTROLLER
//-----THIS IS WHERE I CALL **login.js**
//module koneksi ke database
const koneksiModul = require('./controller/koneksi');
var koneksi = koneksiModul.koneksi;
//-----
//-----
//-----
//-----
//-----
//-----KONFIGURASI
const app = express();

app.set('views','./view')
app.set('view engine','pug')
app.use(express.static('./public'))
app.listen(3000,  koneksi)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) 
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(session({
   secret: 'secret',
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true,
   cookie: {secure: false }
 }));

app.use(flash());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   res.app.locals = req.flash();
   next();
});
```

and here's my **login.js** :

```
const koneksiModul = require('./koneksi');
var koneksi = koneksiModul.koneksi;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

class LoginUser {
   constructor(req, res) {
      this.req = req;
      this.res = res;
   }

   proses_login_user() {
      let username = this.req.body.log_username;
      let password = this.req.body.log_password;

      let sql = `SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE username = ?`;

      if (username && password) {
         koneksi.query(sql, [username], (err1, result, fields) => {
            if(result.length > 0) {
               bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].pass_enc, function(err2, result1) {
                  if(result1) {

                     //_____THE ERROR COMES FROM HERE

                     this.req.session.username=username;
                     this.req.flash('msg_login_sukses','Selamat datang : ')
                     this.res.redirect('/beranda');
                  } else {
                     this.req.flash('msg_login_gagal','Gagal! : ')
                     this.req.flash('isi','Username/Password salah')
                     this.res.redirect('/');
                     throw err2;
                  } 
               });
            } else {
               this.req.flash('msg_login_gagal','Gagal! : ')
               this.req.flash('isi','Akun tidak ditemukan')
               this.res.redirect('/');
               throw err1;
            }
         })
      }
   }
}

module.exports = LoginUser;
```